Flutter can't scan bluetooth devices
So i have an POS app that can print a receipt to customer, and i use this package to scan the bluetooth devices : https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_blue_plus
it work on IOS devices but when i switch to android, the bluetooth printer can't be found, and there's nothing printed on the console
I have try to change the android.manifest and added this permission
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_SCAN" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_CONNECT" android:usesPermissionFlags="neverForLocation" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />

but the problem still persist

The first thing to check is whether your app is correctly requesting the necessary permissions at runtime. Certain permissions must be explicitly granted by the user during runtime. As highlighted in the Android Developers guide:

The BLUETOOTH_ADVERTISE, BLUETOOTH_CONNECT, and BLUETOOTH_SCAN
permissions are runtime permissions. Therefore, you must explicitly
request user approval in your app before you can look for Bluetooth
devices, make a device discoverable to other devices, or communicate
with already-paired Bluetooth devices.

If you haven’t implemented runtime permission requests, your app won’t be able to perform Bluetooth scans or connections, which could explain why your printer is being detected.
If you are already implementing runtime permissions in your code, the next thing I would experiment with is removing the neverForLocation flag from the BLUETOOTH_SCAN permission in your AndroidManifest.xml. Although this flag typically only affects scanning results for Bluetooth beacons, there are cases where it can impact the scan results for other devices. It’s unlikely to be the main cause of your issue but removing it can help eliminate any potential conflicts related to location-based scanning.
Check the links below for more info:-

Flutter on Android 13: Unable to scan for devices
How to fix Flutter Bluetooth scan permissions
Problem for granting permissions in Flutter

